# How can I get a SpreadSheet Google using XHR?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get Spreadsheet data Google. So, to do this, I've seen the [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) and [basic information about Query object](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#query) and, in this second link, it appears the "fast" info to realize a query. The problem is that, because of my JS skills, **I don't understand** `opt_options` parameter of the `google.visualization.Query` function.

I mean, I know that I have to send my query to get the data, but I don't know how to do it because the `sendMethod` description of `opt_parameters` doesn't seems me sufficiently detailed for write the JS code whether I want use the XHR method.

Also I've seen that I can include the query in the SpreadSheet link. Anyways, I only want to get the data transformed into JSON data or something that I can manipulate.

I consider that this question **can be useful** for this people like me that are beginning to get data from other pages and don't know how to do it exactly.

PD: Yes, I've read XMLHttpRequest info from MDN.

**EDIT:** I've supposed that `Query` object send XHR and I only have to concern me for `send` method of `Query` and its callback that is an instance of `QueryResponse` class. The problem is that I don't retrieve anything! Here is my code once again:

```
var query;

function getData(DATA_SOURCE_URL){
    query = new google.visualization.Query(DATA_SOURCE_URL);
    query.setTimeout(10);
    query.send(displayData);
    console.log("Query has been sent");
}

function displayData(response){ //This function doesn't works
    if(response.isError()){
        console.log(response.getDetailedMessage());
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    alert(data);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the spreadsheet you are trying to access give access to everyone with a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP).*

Finally I got rid of Query Language Reference and all stuff about Google and I discovered TableTop to request data from spreadsheets. It's very easy to use and its documentation is simple and concise. My main aim was bring data from a spreadsheet to my JS application.